# Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'int *' to 'Bird *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pointers, object

Bird, GameWorld and GameScene are three custom classes in my project.

I've an object of type Bird(as a property) in the class Gameworld. I've objects of type Bird and Gameworld in the class GameScene. Now in Gamescene class, when I do:

```
_bird = [_gameWorld bird];
```

an error is alerted:

> Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'int *' to 'Bird
>   *' is disallowed with ARC

Why this is happening?

Edit:

GameScene.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "Bird.h"
#import "ScrollHandler.h"
#import "Pipe.h"
#import "GameWorld.h"

@interface GameScene : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>{

    int _midPointY;
    float _gameHeight;
    NSString *_gameName;
    NSString *_getReady;
    Bird *_myBird;   

    NSTimeInterval _dt;
    float bottomScrollerHeight;

    GameWorld *_myWorld;   

}

@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode* backgroundImageNode;
@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode* greenBird;

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastSpawnTimeInterval;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastUpdateTimeInterval;


@end
```

GameWorld.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "Bird.h"
#import "ScrollHandler.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GameState){
    MENU,
    READY,
    RUNNING,
    GAMEOVER,
    HIGHSCORE
};

@interface GameWorld : NSObject <ScrollHandlerDelegate>{

    float _runTime;
    GameState _currentState;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) ScrollHandler *scroller;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Bird *bird;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int midPointY;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int score;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *bg;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *birds;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *birdNode; 

@end
```

GameScene.m

```
#import "GameScene.h"


#define UPWARD_PILLER @"Upward_Green_Pipe"
#define Downward_PILLER @"Downward_Green_Pipe"

static const uint32_t pillerCategory            =  0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t birdCategory        =  0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t grassCategory             =  0x1 << 2;


static const float BG_VELOCITY = (TIME * 60);

static inline CGPoint CGPointAdd(const CGPoint a, const CGPoint b)
{
    return CGPointMake(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}

static inline CGPoint CGPointMultiplyScalar(const CGPoint a, const CGFloat b)
{
    return CGPointMake(a.x * b, a.y * b);
}



@implementation GameScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {       

        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
        self.yScale = -1;

        //To detect collision detection
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
        _myWorld = [[GameWorld alloc] initWithMidPointY:_midPointY];
        [self initGameObjects];
        [self initAssets];
        [self setCoinAnimation];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) initGameObjects {

    _myBird = [_myWorld bird]; //here is the problem

}

-(void) initAssets {

    //initialize other assets

}

-(void) setCoinAnimation {

    //initialize other assets

}

@end
```

Bird.h

```
#import "GameWorld.h"

@import UIKit;

@interface Bird : NSObject {

    CGPoint _position;
    CGPoint _velocity;
    CGPoint _acceleration;

    float _rotation;
    float _originalY;
    int _width;
    int _height;
    int _dieCount;
    bool _isAlive;    

}

@end
```

Note:I just found out that when I remove the import "Gameworld.h"
 from "Bird.h", the error disappears and it is working. The import was made there accidentally and it is not needed. But I don't why it caused the error.

Comment: Can you post your `property` declaration code?

Comment: Sure. @property (nonatomic, strong) Bird *bird;

Comment: And how declared _bird (or property bird) on Gamescene?

Comment: Kindly, provide with the `property` declaration in both the files, `Gameworld` and `Gamescene`.

Comment: May be you implemented getter of the bird property on GameWorld class and forgot return Bird reference?

Comment: @DroidHeaven in one of the files you may be declaring the **property** `Bird` as  `int`

Comment: @stosha sorry for being late. here it is:  In GameScene, bird is declared as an ivar    Bird *_bird;

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala Gameworld interface: @property(nonatomic, strong) Bird *bird;  In GameScene interface:     Bird *_myBird; (as ivar)

Comment: @stosha: I checked the GameWorld class. I haven't written any getters to overwrite the default ones provided by the property

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala I've checked every file. nowhere it is declared as anything other than Bird class. (Somehow it is returned as integer pointer because the autocompletion of [_gameWorld bird] indicates that it is returning 'int*' type).

Comment: Also please note that I may not be able to respond to your comments soon(faulty internet). I will get back to you as soon as I could.

Comment: @DroidHeaven By the way you can declare @property(nonatomic, weak) Bird *bird; instead of  Bird *_myBird; declare. Then write something like self.bird = _gameWorld.bird; I'm not sure it will solve problem.

Comment: Sure. I'll check that and will get back to you.

Comment: @stosha `bird` is not an UIElement and is not referenced from a xib. The user himself is the owner of the object, so he SHOULD NOT declare it as `weak`. And the question what has been asked, this solution is not relevant. The xcode is giving warning about implicit type conversion and not about retain cycle.

Comment: @DroidHeaven `Gameworld` inherits from ?

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala my apologies for being late. `Gameworld` inherits from NSObject.

Comment: Alright, as a last thought, could you update your question and paste your interface and implementation code for both the files?

Comment: Sure. I will post them here.

Comment: Hey, I've pasted the code. Also I've found out what causes the issue. Please read the note at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you mentioned in the end, thats was the only issue.

**So what was happening?**

When you imported `Gameworld` to your `Bird` interface file, in that, your `Gameworld` itself had a variable named `bird` which was of type `Bird`. You then went ahead and defined the `Bird` class in the subsequent lines. Before that the compiler din't knew what the `Bird` object is and it by default assumes it as `int`.

If you any how want to to declare `Gameworld` object in your `Bird` class, then instead of importing it your interface, you just need to use forward declaration, i.e.

```
@class Gameworld;
```

This tells the compiler that a **Class** do exist with the name `Gameworld`.

Answer (score 2):

Import statements must be linear, but you had a loop. `GameScene.m` -> `GameScene.h` -> `Bird.h` -> `GameWorld.h` -> `Bird.h`.

Because of this, when `GameWorld.h` had `#import "Bird.h"`, the compiler saw that `Bird.h` was already imported and didn't import it. The problem was `@interface Bird` had not been defined yet, so `GameWorld` didn't have the proper interface for `Bird`.